# JQuery Dialog show effect doesn't work, every other parameter does

Tags: jquery

I have this code to popup a JQuery dialog box:

```
$( "#dialogBox" ).dialog({
   height: 585,
   width: 620,  
   modal: true,
   resizable: false,    
   show: { 
     effect: 'fold', 
     complete: function() { $("#txtEmail").focus(); }
   }                                
});
```

The dialog box appears correctly except for the effect. No matter what effect I choose, the box appears the same way (grows from top left to bottom right).

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't supported in jQuery UI **1.8**, though it's slated for **1.9**: http://dev.jqueryui.com/ticket/2358

For now you can just do the effect itself (no options) like this:

```
show: 'fold',
```

Comment: Darn, well I guess that explains it. Any other suggestions on how to focus the text field after the dialog has finished animating?

Comment: @Jon - You could fold hide and fold the area in the `open` callback, then do the `focus` as the callback, not pretty (and won't queue) but it works.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up adding a SetTimeout to the focus function which seemed to do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "#dialogBox" ).dialog({
   open: function(){$("#txtEmail").focus();},
   height: 585,
   width: 620,  
   modal: true,
   resizable: false,    
   show: 'fold'
});
```

Comment: I can see it focus the fields when the dialog opens, but once the animation finishes it loses focus.